# Laravel 5.6 storing files in database and saving them

Tags: php, laravel

The user can upload 1 or multiple files like images for example as attachments when creating a new ImageRequest.

My goal is to save the attachments in the database or at lea so I know what attachments belongs to what ImageRequest. And obviously I need to save the files.

This is simplified what my ImageRequest table looks like:

```
Schema::create('image_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('attachment')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is my file upload in my form.

```
<input
        id="input-b3"
        name="attachment[]"
        type="file"
        class="file"
        multiple
        data-show-upload="false"
        data-show-caption="true"
        data-msg-placeholder="Select {files} for upload..."
>
```

This is the logic for handling the store:

```
private function createNewImageRequest(StoreImageRequestRequest $request)
{
    // create new imagerequest
    $imageRequest = new ImageRequest(
        array_merge(
            $request->all(),
            ['status' => self::STATUS_NEW]
        )
    );

    // save new image request binded to the user
    $imageRequest = Auth::user()->imageRequests()->save($imageRequest);

    // save files
    $request->file('attachment')->storeAs(
        'attachments', $request->user()->id
    );

    return $imageRequest->id;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Array to string conversion

This is probably because my column type is string and I am trying to save an array so I need to serialize it but I have no idea how or if what I am doing is even gonna work.

Never thought it would be this hard to store attachment in Laraven, especially since Laravel makes the basic things for a web app fairly easy.

Comment: What line is this error occurring? Instead of storing the actual file, so the path to the file in the db and whenever you need the file, you can access it by getting its path from the db. Also, if you are set on storing the file then you need to change `$table->string('attachment')->nullable();` to a blob, not a string.

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to just store the path. @Script47

Comment: @Script47 but the problem is that there can be multiple files so the column in my sql need to accept and array or serialized array I don't know how to do this with my current code

Comment: Then simply `json_encode` your array of file paths and when retrieving, `json_decode` (second parameter true) and loop through the array to get the paths.

Comment: @Script47 I am sorry but I don't understand, I will look for an other way. Thanks

Comment: An alternative would be a 1:m relation between a `image_request` and `attachments` -> One `image_request` has multiple attachments. Create one `attachments` table and add a relationship between `image_requests` and this one. Delete the attachments column from the `image_requests` table

Answer (score 0):

For my project i do that and is work in your construct put this

```
   $this->upload_path = 'img'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'blog'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $this->storage = Storage::disk('public');
```

after that in your function use this :

```
 // Uploading Image
    if (array_key_exists('featured_image', $input)) {
        $this->deleteOldFile($blog);
        $input = $this->uploadImage($input);
    }
```

and this is deleteOldFile

```
 public function deleteOldFile($model)
{
    $fileName = $model->featured_image;

    return $this->storage->delete($this->upload_path.$fileName);
}
```

and UploadImage

public function uploadImage($input)
{
    $avatar = $input['featured_image'];

```
if (isset($input['featured_image']) && !empty($input['featured_image'])) {
    $fileName = time().$avatar->getClientOriginalName();

    $this->storage->put($this->upload_path.$fileName, file_get_contents($avatar->getRealPath()));

    $input = array_merge($input, ['featured_image' => $fileName]);

    return $input;
}
```

}